# SQLite: Getting value 0 from a query when insertions work correctly

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, left-join, android-sqlite

I have a Table `Notes (_Id, Title, Body, Category)` and a Table `Categories (_Id, Name)`, referencing Category to Categories._Id.

With this method I create a Note in my SQLite Database.

```
/**
 * Create a new note using the title and body provided, and associated to
 * the category with row id provided. If the note is successfully created
 * return the new rowId for that note, otherwise return  a -1 to indicate failure.
 *
 * @param title the title of the note
 * @param body the body of the note
 * @param category the category associated to the note
 * @return rowId or -1 if failed
 */
public long createNote(String title, String body, String category) {
    if (title == null || title.equals("") || body == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(NOTE_KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(NOTE_KEY_BODY, body);
        // If it has associated a category
        if (!category.equals("No Category")) {
            Cursor idCategory = fetchCategory(category);
            long catId = idCategory.getLong(idCategory.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            initialValues.put(NOTE_KEY_CAT, catId);
        // Else, it has no category
        } else {
            initialValues.put(NOTE_KEY_CAT, (Byte) null);
        }
        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_NOTE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
}
```

And with this, I get all the notes of my database.

```
/**
 * Return a Cursor over the list of all notes in the database
 *
 * @param mode - if TITLE, it returns the list ordered by the title of the notes.
 *             - if CATEGORY, it returns the list ordered by the category of the notes.
 *             - it returns null in another case.
 * @param category - category of the notes to return (No Category if none)
 * @return Cursor over all notes
 */
public Cursor fetchAllNotes(String mode, String category) {
    //// Order
    String order;
    // Mode is Title
    if (mode.equals("TITLE")) {
        order = NOTE_KEY_TITLE;
    // Mode is Categories
    } else if (mode.equals("CATEGORY")) {
        order = CAT_KEY_NAME;
    // A forbidden mode
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    // No category filter if it is No Category
    String cat;
    if (category.equals("No Category")) {
        cat = "";
    } else {
        cat = " WHERE " + CAT_KEY_NAME + "='" + category + "'";
    }                                     // Left outer because there are notes without category
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_NOTE_TABLE + " LEFT OUTER JOIN " + DATABASE_CAT_TABLE +
            " C ON " + NOTE_KEY_CAT + "=C." + CAT_KEY_ROWID + cat + " ORDER BY " + order;
    return mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

Edit:

1. I realize several `createNote()` operations, and notes are correctly inserted (and the method returns the correct rowId of the note created [1, 2, ... ]).
2. I realize that  from`fetchAllNotes()` operation, all the notes are returned. However, the notes with `No Category` have their rowId attribute as 0 (when the `createNote()` returned me a positive value). And the notes with a category have a positive rowId value, but not the correct.

For example:

```
CreateNote (Title: A, Body: B, Category: No Category). Returns 1
CreateNote (Title: C, Body: D, Category: No Category). Returns 2
CreateNote (Title: E, Body: F, Category: I have a Category). Returns 3
```

FetchAllNotes() Returns:

```
1. Note(0, A, B, No Category)
2. Note(0, C, D, No Category)
3. Note(1, E, F, I have a Category)`
```

Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: Your question is unclear, unable to find out what you are facing issue? Please ask the concrete question.

Comment: Can you print `query`, before executing it?

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi Query is `SELECT * FROM notes LEFT OUTER JOIN categories C ON category=C._id ORDER BY title`

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi Yes, it is the generated query, printed on screen. The **+ cat +** addition is just a filter. When parameter **category = Lands**, the query generated is `SELECT * FROM notes LEFT OUTER JOIN categories C ON category=C._id WHERE name='Lands' ORDER BY title`.

Comment: Exactly. The desired output I wanted is `1. Note(1, A, B, No Category) 2. Note(2, C, D, No Category) 3. Note(3, E, F, I have a Category)`. (I am writing the name of the category instead of its identifier for clarity)

Comment: It worked! I forgot that join also returns `Category` attributes. Thanks @HrundiV.Bakshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `*` with the full field list (which is the BEST PRACTICE).
So to return only the needed fields in the Cursor.